# Get only one lemma for each word in the token list.

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordnet

I need only one word in the synonym set of wordnet for each word in token list and not all. How do I pass the index of the very first lemma for each token. Here's my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

lemmas = []
text = ['one', 'oasis', 'halliday', 'avatar', 'time', 'school', 'year', 'thing', 'old', 'stack', 'every', 'world',
        'egg', 'game', 'around', 'real', 'name', 'room', 'still', 'even', 'began', 'trailer', 'much',
         'anorak', 'player']
for token in text:
    lemmas += [synset.lemmas()[0].name() for synset in wn.synsets(token)]
print(list(set(lemmas)))

print(len(lemmas))
print(len(text))
```

Length of text is 25 but length of lemmas is 203.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you provide sample input / output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

lemmas = []
text = ['one', 'oasis', 'halliday', 'avatar', 'time', 'school', 'year', 'thing', 'old', 'stack', 'every', 'world',
        'egg', 'game', 'around', 'real', 'name', 'room', 'still', 'even', 'began', 'trailer', 'much',
         'anorak', 'player']
for token in text:
    synsets = wn.synsets(token)
    if synsets:
        lemmas.append(synsets[0].lemmas()[0].name())

print(list(set(lemmas)))
print(len(lemmas))
print(len(text))
```

**Output**

```
['old', 'stack', 'about', 'school', 'universe', 'evening', 'room', 'egg', 'game', 'one', 'player', 'thing', 'name', 'every', 'get_down', 'much', 'year', 'still', 'time', 'real_number', 'oasis', 'dawdler', 'embodiment', 'parka']
24
25
```

The length of lemmas is 24 because it appears the word `halliday` does not have a synset. This is confirmed by:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

synsets = wn.synsets('halliday')
print(synsets)
```

**Output**

```
[]
```